# Can an event be used as an event listener?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to expose some events from a private object which is contained inside the object I am creating and it looks like the compiler is happy with this:

```
private WindowUpdateServer _windowUpdateServer;

public event WindowUpdateHandler WindowUpdated;

public RecieveWindowFramesManager() {

    _windowUpdateServer = new WindowUpdateServer();

    _windowUpdateServer.ExistingWindowUpdated += WindowUpdated; // ExistingWindowUpdated is a WindowUpdateHandler
}
```

But after RecieveWindowFramesManager is initialized _windowUpdateServer.ExistingWindowUpdated == null.

Am I missing something here - it seems this should work?

It is worth noting that after RecieveWindowFramesManager is initialized I attach an event listener to WindowUpdated but it never gets called (even though _windowUpdateServer.ExistingWindowUpdated gets fired).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
public event WindowUpdateEventHandler WindowUpdated
{ 
    add{ _windowUpdateServer.ExistingWindowUpdated += value; }
    remove{ _windowUpdateServer.ExistingWindowUpdated -= value; }
}
```

It has some issues if you're actually using the sender argument in the event handlers, though; it'll point to the inner object rather than the one you're getting the events from.

Comment: Nice! More elegant even then my solution!

Comment: I just tried this out and it works perfectly.  Really nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, but I think this only assigns those handlers from the WindowUpdated event, that were set when the += operation took place. Since it is a constructor, the list was empty. To do what you want, create your own event handler for ExistingWindowUpdated and fire the WindowUpdated event from there.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation. ArildF's solution works very well in my situation - so I have accepted his answer as more fitting.